# how to give title to video played using movie player in matlab

Tags: matlab

In my project I want to play number of videos using the matlab function `implay()`. In matlab, figures can distinguished by using the command `title`. Is there a similar way to attach titles to videos created with `implay`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a handle to the [`implay`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/implay.html) object. Its parent is the figure. So set the parent's `'Name'` property to the desired title:

```
load cellsequence %// example taken from `implay`'s help
h = implay(cellsequence,10); %// call `implay` and get a handle
set(h.Parent, 'Name', 'Write your title here') %// set title
```

The result (in Matlab R2010b) is:

[image]